# How to setup a node server (with nginx sat on top) to work with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have a node express application which communicates with mongodb and serves back the response in JSON format after doing some processing. The application works as expected when run on a local machine.

This is how my connect code looks

```
await MongoClient.connect(uri, async function (err, client) {
    ...
}
```

However, I have deployed the application to an aws ec2 instance following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c) where I added nginx as a layer on top of my node application. Now I get a `504 Gateway Time-out` on any routes that try to connect to mongodb.

The server block in my nginx configuration

```
 server {
     listen         80 default_server;
     listen         [::]:80 default_server;
     server_name    localhost;
     root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       } 
 }
```

I understand that mongodb does not use HTTP, which is what nginx uses for communication. So I have tried to follow [this tutorial](https://blog.khophi.co/mongodb-behind-nginx-proxy/) but have had no luck.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you install mongo on that ec2 machine? I would confirm your connection string. Also by default, `Nginx` gives up after 1 minute and returns a 504.

Comment: I have mongodb as a dependancy in my package.json.

Comment: The mongo server is where?

Comment: The database is in the cloud. I'm using MongoDB Atlas

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had completely forgotten to whitelist my server's IP address when I deployed the app to an ec2 instance. Hence why everything worked as expected locally (my local IP address was whitelisted).

This had nothing to do with NGINX. My mistake.